# WPF TreeView images based on Tag property

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm trying to create a WPF treeview which should add images infront of the TreeviewItem (node) based on the TreeViewItem's `Tag property`. I want this to work with this property because I'm going to let my PowerShell script create the treenodes dynamically during execution.

This is the XAML I'm using inside my WPF application:

```
<TreeView Name="MainTreeview1" Margin="10,248,10,151" Padding="-2,1,1,1">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image Name="TreeNodeIMG" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill">
                <Image.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="images\ImageForTag0.png"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="images\ImageForTag1.png"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
                </Image.Style>
              </Image>
              <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.Resources>

  <TreeViewItem Header="TestWithIMG1" Tag="0"/>
  <TreeViewItem Header="TestWithIMG2" Tag="1"/>

</TreeView>
```

If this is possible with an treeviewitem template I'm fine with that aswell aslong as I am possible to easy differentiate treenodes.

Comment: Of course it's possible..I don't understand where is the question. By the way, this is not good practice to implement this solution. You should create an appropriate model class with `ImagePath` property and bind to it as the `TreeViewItem` `DataContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible but you need to define binding source differently, because Tag isn't a property of DataContext, it is TreeViewItem property

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" 
               Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="images\ImageForTag0.png"/>
  </DataTrigger>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" 
               Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="images\ImageForTag1.png"/>
  </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```